# How spy mock function in object props when tests with jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a prop mock object inside two mock function. I need to spy both of them and I don't know how to spy.

This is an example:

myComponent.js

```js
function Package(props) {
  const { lockUI } = props
  lockUI.set();
  // ...
}
```

myComponent.test.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Package from 'src/Package';
import { cleanup, render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Package Unit Test', () => {
    let props;

    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            lockUI                                 : {
                set   : jest.fn(),
                unset : jest.fn(),
            },
        };
    });

    afterEach(cleanup);

    test('testing example', () => {
        render(<Package {...props} />);
        expect(props.lockUI.set).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Response console:

```
 Expected number of calls: 1
 Received number of calls: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to declare the setSpy and unsetSpy first and plug them into the component

```
import React from 'react';
import Package from 'src/Package';
import { cleanup, render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Package Unit Test', () => {
    const setSpy = jest.fn();
    const unsetSpy = jest.fn();
    let props;

    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            lockUI                                 : {
                set   : setSpy,
                unset : unsetSpy,
            },
        };
    });

    afterEach(cleanup);

    test('testing example', () => {
        render(<Package {...props} />);
        expect(setSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```